# Как удалить строку в listView по нажатию кнопки при условии что все поля строки пустые?

Tags: delphi

```
if (Item.SubItems.Text='') and (Item.SubItems.Text='') and (Item.SubItems.Text='')
and (Item.SubItems.Text='') and (Item.SubItems.Text='') 
then begin 
ListView1.RowSelect:=True;
ListView1.Items[6].Selected:= true;
ListView1.Selected.Free;
end;
```

Вылетает окно с ошибкой (Access violation at address 004754E7 in module 'Project1'...)

**UPD**

По следующему варианту просто никакой реакции:

```
For i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1 do begin
if ListView1.Items.Item[i].Caption='' then
ListView1.Items.Item[i].Delete
end
```

**UPD 2**

На вид все получилось, строка визуально пропадает но при сохранении в ini строка восстанавливается или не пропадает вовсе:

```
j:=1;
For i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1 do begin
if ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[j]='' then
ListView1.Items.Item[i].Delete
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте точку останова и выполняйте в отладчике по шагам.
Ставлю $5, что в ListView нету шестой строки.

```
ListView1.Items[6].Selected:= true; // там точно есть строка с номером 6?
ListView1.Selected.Free; // так делать нельзя
```

`RowSelect` нужно установить в дизайнере.

У `ListView` для работы с элементами есть методы `Add` и `Delete`.

Comment: Не знал что 6 - это строка, думал что это количество пунктов в строке.<br>

RowSelect ставить нельзя, можно только установить в коде и сразу же убрать, поскольку у меня при клике по пункту производится его редактирование.

Как же тогда будет выглядеть удаление строки в которой все поля пусты?

Comment: `RowSelect` - это свойство определяет будет ли подсвечиваться вся строка или только первый столбец при выделении элемента (если в `ListView` стоит табличный вид). Читайте справку.

`ListView1.Items.Item[i].Caption` - это заголовок элемента (нулевой столбец). Если вам нужно проверить остальные столбцы, то к ним нужно обращаться так:

    ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[j]

Первый столбец: j = 0
Второй столбец: j = 1
и т.д.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, обновил вопрос, визуально удаление срабатывает но при сохранении в ini, оказывается что удаления не было.

Comment: @hkpp
Покажите как вы делаете сохранение в ini. Лучше отдельным вопросом.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, http://hashcode.ru/questions/331341/delphi-как-удалить-строку-с-пустыми-полями-в-listview